# load page with detailsview in insert mode

Tags: asp.net, gridview, detailsview

I have an ASP.Net page with a gridview and detailsview...when I click an item in the gridview, the detailsview is displayed and populated with the details of the selected user from the gridview....currently, when I first load the page and no user is selected from the gridview, I don't see the detailsview...how can I display the detailsview in insert mode when the page is loaded...before a user has been selected from the gridview?

Answer (score 5):

```
DetailsView1.DefaultMode = DetailsViewMode.Insert;
```

Comment: thanks, this works, but the detailsview remains in insert mode now...when I click a user from the gridview, the detailsview displays in insert mode