# How to bind data to DropDownList in UpdatePanel inside DetailsView

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, drop-down-menu, updatepanel

I use DetailsView to insert rows in database. Row has fields id, subcategory_id etc. I want to fill dynamically dropdownlist ddl_subcategories, which is used in TemplateField. Selected item value of first dropdownlist ddl_categories is used as parameter for generating collection for ddl_subcategories. I try it with using UpdatePanel, but method DataBind returns error "Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.".

There's code of web form

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="dvw" runat="server" Height="50px" Width="125px" 
    AutoGenerateRows="False" DataSourceID="ods"
    DefaultMode="Insert" DataKeyNames="Section_id"
    OnDataBound="dvw_DataBound" OnItemUpdated="dvw_ItemUpdated" 
    OnItemCommand="dvw_ItemCommand">
    <Fields>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Category" >
       <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_categories" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" DataSourceID="ods_categories"
                  DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Category_id" OnSelectedIndexChanged="category_select_index_changed"/>
       </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>            

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Subcategory" >
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_subcategories" runat="server"                               
                          SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Subcategory_id") %>' />
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddl_categories" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
...
 </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
```

There is part of behind-code:

```
protected void category_select_index_changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddl_categories = (DropDownList)dvw.FindControl("ddl_categories");
    List<SUBCATEGORY> sections =  SUBCATEGORY.Select_all_by_parameters(Int32.Parse(ddl_categories.SelectedValue));//Select all subcategories by id of category
    DropDownList ddl_subcategories= (DropDownList)dvw.FindControl("ddl_subcategories");

    ddl_subcategories.DataSource = sections;
    ddl_subcategories.DataTextField = "Name";
    ddl_subcategories.DataValueField = "Subcategory_id";
    ddl_subcategories.DataBind();
}
```

What is my error?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have all of the code? I don't see ddl_subcategories in your codebehind

Comment: In <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776407/load-page-with-detailsview-in-insert-mode/18049579#18049579">this page </a> is your answer. You must use correctly from DetailsView.

Comment: In <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776407/load-page-with-detailsview-in-insert-mode/18049579#18049579">this page </a> is your answer. you must use correctly from DetailsView.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you are data binding the subcategories dropdown, there is no DataBinding Context (see [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1526436.aspx) for more info, pay attention to David Fowler's comments).  I don't think the UpdatePanel is the issue as the behavior is the same with or without it (and if you wrap the entire DetailsView in an UpdatePanel).

A solution is to load the items individually instead of data binding the control.  It seems a little clumsy, I admit, but it does work.

```
protected void category_select_index_changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddl_categories = (DropDownList)dvw.FindControl("ddl_categories");
    IEnumerable<SUBCATEGORY> sections = new SUBCATEGORY[] { new SUBCATEGORY() { Name = "First " + ddl_categories.SelectedValue, Subcategory_id = "1" }, new SUBCATEGORY() { Name = "Second", Subcategory_id = "2" } };
    DropDownList ddl_subcategories = (DropDownList)dvw.FindControl("ddl_subcategories");

    ddl_subcategories.Items.Clear();
    foreach (SUBCATEGORY cat in sections)
    {
        ddl_subcategories.Items.Add(new ListItem(cat.Name, cat.Subcategory_id));
    }
}
```

A better option would be to not use Bind in the control, and just set the value in the ObjectDataSource's parameters on Insert/Update.

Update:  You can set the [ObjectDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.aspx) value directly.  Add an event handler for the [OnInserting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.inserting.aspx) (or [OnUpdating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.updating.aspx) as needed) as follows:

```
protected void ods_OnInserting(object sender, ObjectDataSourceMethodEventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList ddl_subcategories = (DropDownList)dvw.FindControl("ddl_subcategories");
    e.InputParameters["Subcategory_id"] = ddl_subcategories.SelectedValue;
}
```

I can't actually test this right now, but it should be close.

Comment: I tried that way. Fields of dropdownlist were filled up correctly.  But form sent null-value from dropdownlist. What is reason?
One more question. Is any way to set value in the ObjectDataSource programmatically?

Comment: If I don't use update panel, ddl_subcategories returns correct value. But if I don't use update panel, I won't able to realize behaviour of controls without postback.

Comment: If I use pure AJAX (web services and js) without update panel, it works. But it's interesting why it doesn't work with update panel.

Comment: The reason that the first way is not returning values is because the data is not being filled at the correct time in the page lifecycle (http://john-sheehan.com/blog/net-cheat-sheet-aspnet-page-life-cycle-common-events/).  I don't know why the update panel causes the problem, it doesn't work with or without the update panel in my tests.  I updated my answer with details of how to set the ObjectDataSource value programmatically on insert/update.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I decided to use pure AJAX. I'll prepare new question. I found strange error in using 0-value in dropdownlist. Here is my new post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442019/formatexception-in-detailsview-which-uses-dynamically-inserted-value-for-item-of

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `Bind("DBFieldName")` and add the following line to the `YourDetailsView_ItemInserting` like the following:

```
e.Values["DBFieldName"] = 
  ((DropDownList)YourDetailsView.Rows[1].FindControl("ddl_categories")).SelectedValue;
```

Note: Don't forget to replace the Rows[1] to your Dropdown templete field index.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the entire DetailsView with the update panel to see if that makes a difference...